# Disable button is not working inside colorbox

Tags: php, jquery, colorbox

I'm showing the form inside the colorbox and calling it through the ajax. I want to disable the submit button after the click. I have disabled it through the jquery, it is working but did not submit the form value.Please let me know how can I resolve it.I'm using the following code.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".submitonce").click(function(){
        $(".submitonce").attr('disabled','disabled');           
        });
           });
     </script>

      echo "<div id='".$divid."' style='display:none'>
    <div style='margin:10px 0px 0px 0px'    align='center'><h4>".$title."</h4></div>
    <div style='margin:30px 0px 0px 0px'><center></center></div>
     <div>".$description."</div>   
   <div style='margin:10px'>
    <center><form action='' name='theform3' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='p-id' value='".$prodid."' />
  <input type='submit' name='oneclickorder' class='submitonce' 
    value='Confirm' style='size:20px' /></a>
  <input type='button' name='no1' value='Cancel' onclick='tb_remove()'/>
   </form></center></div>
    </div>";
```

Comment: `<blink>` would be a better choice :-) @Seth

Comment: How are you verifying that the form did not submit?  As your form has no action, it's going to be handled by the same page you have your form on?  Is there more to this page that will handle a form submission?

Comment: it is inside the colorbox when I submit the form it goes to the parent page.

Comment: As your form has no action, it should go to the parent page . . . so I ask again, how are you verifying that the form did not submit?

Comment: I'm submitting  the value that is in hidden field.

Comment: My point is that the p-id is most likely submitting, but you're not handling the input.  If you use a browser's developer tools, what does the POST show?

Answer (score 0):

You just didn't open the form tag.
Also the input type should be "submit"

Comment: plz check it again the code,there are two button one is submit and other is button type and I have also opened the form tag

Answer (score 0):

have you solved it? seems to work for me, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6WpAL/)

I am not sure, if your question has the entire code, but with what you gave, after the `<script>` tag, it needs to be enclosed in `<form>` tags like this:

```
 <form>
 <div style='margin:10px 0px 0px 0px'    align='center'><h4>".$title."</h4></div>
<div style='margin:30px 0px 0px 0px'><center></center></div>
 <div>".$description."</div>
```

Edit: say `<form id='main_form'>`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submitonce").click(function(){
    $('#main_form').submit();
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');           
    });
```

});​

Comment: NO. Problem is when I disabled it then form is not submitting the content.

Comment: after disabling it, the form would not submit, as the button becomes inactive. you need to submit it before disabling it.

Comment: i edited my answer, take a look. i added an id='main_form' to the form tag.

Comment: how can disabled it after form submit?

Comment: can u show the code for just the `<form>`? does it look  something like `<form method="post" action="url_to_submit_to" />` ?

Comment: <form action='' name='theform3' method='post'>

Comment: `action` needs to be the page url, u need to submit the form to. look at the manual http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp